# proguardDebugAndroidTest Execution Failing with FileNotFoundException for mapping.txt with -dontobfuscate flag in proguard configuration

Tags: android, proguard, android-instrumentation

Even though our application does not use obfuscation, we are seeing a FileNotFoundException for mapping.txt when we try to run `proguardDebugAndroidTest`.

We do not see this error when generating normal debug or release builds. We only see this error when attempting to make an apk for instrumentation tests:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':StubHub:proguardDebugAndroidTest'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /build/outputs/mapping/debug/mapping.txt (No such file or directory)

We are using Android Studio 1.2 and gradle plugin 1.1.3. Has anyone else run up against this issue and been able to troubleshoot it successfully? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating the `mapping.txt` file in that path should be enough to solve the issue. It worked for me and is running just fine now

Answer (score 1):

Digging up an old question because I struggled with this for quite some time. Namely for me "seeds.txt" was apparently missing. Jorge is right but if someone is getting this exception for any other proguard file, be sure that the proguard directory exists. I don't know why but Android Studio won't generate it on its own.

For instance if it says "FileNotFoundException" for app/proguard/seeds.txt, then create the directory "proguard" in the directory app.